# Traefik doesn't route to proper backend for some containers

Tags: traefik

Some of my frontends aren't routed properly to backend. 
I do have 2 container: 
- portainer;
- homeassistant;
Portainer works properly but homeassistant is not routed properly to backend.

my docker-compose:

```
version: "3.6"
services:

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    container_name: portainer
    domainname: ${DOMAINNAME}
    hostname: portainer
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ${USERDIR}/dockerha/uavportainer/data:/data
      - ${USERDIR}/dockerha/shared:/shared
    environment:
      - TZ=${TZ}
    networks:
      - ${NETWORK_NAME}
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${DOMAINNAME}; PathPrefixStrip: /portainer"
      - "traefik.backend=portainer"
      - "traefik.port=9000"
      - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http"

  homeassistant:
    image: homeassistant/home-assistant
    container_name: homeassistant
    domainname: ${DOMAINNAME}
    hostname: homeassistant
    volumes:
      - ${USERDIR}/dockerha/uavha:/config
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - ${USERDIR}/dockerha/shared:/shared
    ports:
      - "8123:8123"
    environment:
      - PUID=${PUID}
      - PGID=${PGID}
      - TZ=${TZ}
    networks:
      - ${NETWORK_NAME}
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${DOMAINNAME};PathPrefixStrip:/hass"
      - "traefik.backend=hass"
      - "traefik.port=8123"
      - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http"
```

toml file:

```
[accessLog]
  filepath = "/etc/traefik/access.log"
  format = "json"

debug = true

logLevel = "DEBUG" #"ERROR" #DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, PANIC

#InsecureSkipVerify = true
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

# WEB interface of Traefik - it will show web page with overview of frontend an$
[api]
  entryPoint = "traefik"
  dashboard = true
  address = ":8080"
#  usersFile = "/shared/.htpasswd"

# Force HTTPS
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"


[file]
watch = true

[docker]
Endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
Domain = "192.168.56.102"
watch = true
SwarmMode = true
network = "uavhanet"
ExposedRyDefault = false
```

The below are 2 different access logs:

working one:

```
{
  "BackendAddr": "10.0.14.11:9000",
  "BackendName": "backend-portainer",
  "BackendURL": {
    "Scheme": "http",
    "Opaque": "",
    "User": null,
    "Host": "10.0.14.11:9000",
    "Path": "",
    "RawPath": "",
    "ForceQuery": false,
    "RawQuery": "",
    "Fragment": ""
  },
  "ClientAddr": "192.168.56.1:58089",
  "ClientHost": "192.168.56.1",
  "ClientPort": "58089",
  "ClientUsername": "-",
  "DownstreamContentSize": 3,
  "DownstreamStatus": 200,
  "DownstreamStatusLine": "200 OK",
  "Duration": 3927995,
  "FrontendName": "Host-192-168-56-102-PathPrefixStrip-portainer-4",
  "OriginContentSize": 3,
  "OriginDuration": 3468375,
  "OriginStatus": 200,
  "OriginStatusLine": "200 OK",
  "Overhead": 459620,
  "RequestAddr": "192.168.56.102",
  "RequestContentSize": 0,
  "RequestCount": 63,
  "RequestHost": "192.168.56.102",
  "RequestLine": "GET /portainer/api/teams HTTP/1.1",
  "RequestMethod": "GET",
  "RequestPath": "/portainer/api/teams",
  "RequestPort": "-",
  "RequestProtocol": "HTTP/1.1",
  "RetryAttempts": 0,
  "StartLocal": "2019-02-19T12:45:44.966258565Z",
  "StartUTC": "2019-02-19T12:45:44.966258565Z",
  "downstream_Content-Length": "3",
  "downstream_Content-Type": "application/json",
  "downstream_Date": "Tue, 19 Feb 2019 12:45:44 GMT",
  "downstream_X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
  "downstream_X-Xss-Protection": "1; mode=block",
  "level": "info",
  "msg": "",
  "origin_Content-Length": "3",
  "origin_Content-Type": "application/json",
  "origin_Date": "Tue, 19 Feb 2019 12:45:44 GMT",
  "origin_X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
  "origin_X-Xss-Protection": "1; mode=block",
  "request_Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
  "request_Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
  "request_Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
  "request_Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiIsInJvbGUiOjEsImV4cCI6MTU1MDU5ODIzMn0.nOzaZYo7gu3An_nHZMpCqPnQ0XNFEvEfrivZ40RumUI",
  "request_Connection": "keep-alive",
  "request_Cookie": "_ga=GA1.1.364506726.1550080124; _gid=GA1.1.376969405.1550080124; portainer.UI_STATE=%7B%22dismissedInfoPanels%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22dismissedInfoHash%22%3A%22y%2BAiiJOM%2Feqr4gyAl6VKBw%3D%3D%22%7D; pma_lang=en; portainer.pagination_containers=25; portainer.pagination_images=25; _gat=1",
  "request_Referer": "http://192.168.56.102/portainer/",
  "request_User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.67 Safari/537.36",
  "request_X-Forwarded-Prefix": "/portainer",
  "time": "2019-02-19T12:45:44Z"
}
```

not working properly:

```
{
  "BackendAddr": "",
  "BackendName": "Traefik",
  "BackendURL": {
    "Scheme": "",
    "Opaque": "",
    "User": null,
    "Host": "",
    "Path": "/frontend_latest/hass-icons-8b13a1ef.js",
    "RawPath": "",
    "ForceQuery": false,
    "RawQuery": "",
    "Fragment": ""
  },
  "ClientAddr": "192.168.56.1:58071",
  "ClientHost": "192.168.56.1",
  "ClientPort": "58071",
  "ClientUsername": "-",
  "DownstreamContentSize": 19,
  "DownstreamStatus": 404,
  "DownstreamStatusLine": "404 Not Found",
  "Duration": 100373,
  "FrontendName": "backend not found",
  "OriginContentSize": 19,
  "OriginDuration": 13969,
  "OriginStatus": 404,
  "OriginStatusLine": "404 Not Found",
  "Overhead": 86404,
  "RequestAddr": "192.168.56.102",
  "RequestContentSize": 0,
  "RequestCount": 78,
  "RequestHost": "192.168.56.102",
  "RequestLine": "GET /frontend_latest/hass-icons-8b13a1ef.js HTTP/1.1",
  "RequestMethod": "GET",
  "RequestPath": "/frontend_latest/hass-icons-8b13a1ef.js",
  "RequestPort": "-",
  "RequestProtocol": "HTTP/1.1",
  "RetryAttempts": 0,
  "StartLocal": "2019-02-19T12:46:54.875219779Z",
  "StartUTC": "2019-02-19T12:46:54.875219779Z",
  "downstream_Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
  "downstream_X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
  "level": "info",
  "msg": "",
  "origin_Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
  "origin_X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
  "request_Accept": "*/*",
  "request_Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
  "request_Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
  "request_Connection": "keep-alive",
  "request_Cookie": "_ga=GA1.1.364506726.1550080124; _gid=GA1.1.376969405.1550080124; portainer.UI_STATE=%7B%22dismissedInfoPanels%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22dismissedInfoHash%22%3A%22y%2BAiiJOM%2Feqr4gyAl6VKBw%3D%3D%22%7D; pma_lang=en; portainer.pagination_containers=25; portainer.pagination_images=25",
  "request_Referer": "http://192.168.56.102/hass/",
  "request_User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.67 Safari/537.36",
  "time": "2019-02-19T12:46:54Z"
}
```

What's wrong ?
Why I get a 404 and not the a 200 ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the only thing I see is for the first one you requesting correct path /portainer and for the second one, you asking /frontend_latest/, try to ask for the second one /hass

Comment: /frontend_latest/ you are referring automatic redirection by container. I properly call the app in url as /IP/hass/ and it redirects to /frontend_latest/

Comment: in the second case, that you told it doesn't work, you have this "RequestLine": "GET /frontend_latest/hass-icons-8b13a1ef.js HTTP/1.1", this doesn't match any PathPrefixStrip

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, you have this `"RequestLine": "GET /frontend_latest/hass-icons-8b13a1ef.js HTTP/1.1"`, this doesn't match any `PathPrefixStrip`, if when you go to `/IP/hass` you redirect to `/frontend_latest/`  using the traefik ip, from my point of view gets a 404, because traefik doesn't have any rule for `/frontend_latest/`

Comment: But is it possible to configure traefik so that if an application redirects, the prefix is automatically added? How does one make it work?

Comment: @Andrew Savinykh you have two options, you can do the redirect using only traefik or you redirect using the application, if you redirect using the second one you need to configure the rule for the final destination.

Comment: I added the below and it works as become default server, which is not preferable: 
- traefik.frontend.rule=HostRegexp:{catchall:.*}
- traefik.frontend.priority=1
I tried to redirect with traefik but could not figure out. Can you please propose redirection rules. Thank you in advance.